# Call a different method on ActiveRecord objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model which has an associated model attached. There are always two records, e.g. `bike.wheels`. It always has two wheels, one is a front and one is a back.

I want to iterate over this collection of associated records and call a method for the first and then a different method for the second.

I am not sure to approach this. I would supply code but I am yet to find a way other than using `.map` which I am not sure will suffice.

Any information would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why did you delete previous question (along with my answer) and added a new one instead of editing existing?

Comment: apologies I thought I had solved it but hadn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since "there are always two records", you can do:

```
front, rear = bike.wheels
front.method_to_call_on_front(*args)
rear.method_to_call_on_rear(*args)
```

Comment: isnt that assuming that the front, rear are assigned to different variables? At present they are just bike.wheels which then returns the records. Is there no way to iterate over them via bike.wheels.

Comment: The only assumption is that your collection always holds exactly two records. You can do this in Ruby: `var1, var2 = ['var1 content', 'var2 content']`.

Comment: Sorry get exactly what you mean. This is what I am after. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to **iterate** over this collection of associated records and call a method for the first and then a different method for the second.

If each bike has two (or more wheels) and you want to **iterate** over them.

```
bike.wheels.each do |wheel|
  if wheel.front?
    # method for front
  elsif wheel.back?
    # method for back
  else
    # method for spare tire
  end
end
```

otherwise something like:

```
bike.wheels[0].method_for_front
bike.wheels[1].method_for_back
```